# Changing name of attribute field in shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have two files:

- a shapefile called: `Habitat.shp`
- from the ZonalStatisticsAsATable-function a .dbf-file: `ZonalStatisticsTable.dbf`.

In the .dbf-file is a coloumn in which I am interested. It is the `MEAN`-coloumn. I want to join that field to the shapefile. Since I am forced to use the shapefile (there is no way a GDB is possible), I wanted basically to join the `MEAN`-coloumn to the shapefile and change then the name to `Fox_Mean`. Here is my code:

```
Habitat="C:\\Files\\Habitat.shp"
ZonalStatisticsOutputTable="C:\\Files\\ZonalStatisticsTable.dbf"
arcpy.JoinField_management(Habitat, "ZoneID", ZonalStatisticsOutputTable, "ZoneID", "MEAN")
arcpy.AlterField_management(Habitat, "MEAN", "Fox_Mean")
```

However since I am working on a shapefile the `AlterField_management`-tool does not work.

Is there any other way of renaming that `MEAN`-field without using GDB or any other additional library?

I thought maybe about simply renaming the `MEAN`-field in the .dbf-file, but then a new [library is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364984/how-can-i-rename-the-field-names-of-a-dbf-file-when-reading-it-with-dbfpy). An alternative would maybe be to just copy the content of the coloumn to a new field and delete the `MEAN`-field then. However I am unsure if that does not screw everything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating the new field, calculating it, and deleting the old field is the way to go.

```
arcpy.AddField_management (Habitat, "Fox_Mean", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (Habitat, "Fox_Mean", "[MEAN]")
arcpy.DeleteField_management (Habitat, "MEAN")
```